# .Net API to query folder and files in ADL Store

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

We are getting feed from EDS as per configured interval. For example : If push is configured for every 8 hrs. for Employee table then folder structure in ADL would look like :

```
Employee
  20171116
      Employee_20171116_00:00
      Employee_20171116_08:00
      Employee_20171116_16:00
  20171117
      Employee_20171117_00:00
      Employee_20171117_08:00
      Employee_20171117_16:00
```

And so on….

After initial full push, these files will have delta records (there will be indicator in file to differentiate full pull vs delta mode) I am using watermark approach to pull these delta files incrementally; so I will store date and time stamp for last processed file. During next run, I need to pick files came to store after last run. Hence I need to query all file names in ascending order and looking for appropriate client api available to do so.

Thanks in Advance !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your processing requirements, you can use

1. U-SQL. In that case look at file sets.
2. .NET SDK for Azure Data Lake Store: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-data-operations-net-sdk

Comment: thanks !! if it can be achieved by u-sql then i can use u-sql analytic activity in my azure data factory pipeline ? i would be great if you can help me with some sample similar to my above requirement.